# building from source Qpid Messaging API (C++, bindings) [Qpid C++ 1.37.0] - missing files

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, qpid

I am trying to build from sources Qpid Messaging API (`C++, bindings`).
Build is triggered on `RHEL` and all prerequisites mentioned on link below are installed.

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=qpid-cpp.git;a=blob_plain;f=INSTALL.txt;hb=HEAD

yet when reaching step: make all

what i get is this

**error:**

```
Linking CXX shared library libqpidclient.so
[ 86%] Built target qpidclient
Scanning dependencies of target qpidmessaging
[ 86%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/qpidmessaging.dir/qpid/messaging/amqp/AddressHelper.cpp.o
In file included from /home/m020390/qpid_cpp/qpid-cpp-1.37.0/src/qpid/messaging/amqp/AddressHelper.cpp:22:0:
/home/m020390/qpid_cpp/qpid-cpp-1.37.0/src/qpid/messaging/amqp/PnData.h:27:27: fatal error: proton/engine.h: No such file or directory
 #include <proton/engine.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/qpidmessaging.dir/qpid/messaging/amqp/AddressHelper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/qpidmessaging.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [examples/messaging/CMakeFiles/client.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [client] Error 2
```

that would indicate that "`Qpid proton-c` " might be missing but its installed....

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the very INSTALL file you provided the link to:

> Note: If Proton is installed in a non-standard location, there are two
> ways to locate it:
>
> 1. Recommended: use proton 0.7 or later and use the same install prefix    for both Proton and Qpid.
> 2. Using pkg-config: set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to    /lib[64]/pkgconfig before running cmake.

I'd go for method 1 and rebuild Proton specifiyng an install prefix to cmake, this way:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
```

Then use the same prefix for Qpid (i.e. run cmake again, just like the above).

Comment: Yeah, that is what i exactly do. Does not seems to help. still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using these steps.

```
$ wget http://apache.claz.org/qpid/proton/0.18.1/qpid-proton-0.18.1.tar.gz                                                 
$ tar -xf qpid-proton-0.18.1.tar.gz                                                                                        
$ cd qpid-proton-0.18.1/                                                                                                   
$ mkdir bld                                                                                                                
$ cd bld                                                                                                                   
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/testprefix                                                                          
$ make -j8                                                                                                                 
$ make install                                                                                                             
$ cd ../..                                                                                                                 
$ wget http://apache.claz.org/qpid/cpp/1.37.0/qpid-cpp-1.37.0.tar.gz                                                       
$ tar -xf qpid-cpp-1.37.0.tar.gz                                                                                           
$ cd qpid-cpp-1.37.0/                                                                                                      
$ mkdir bld                                                                                                                
$ cd bld                                                                                                                   
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/testprefix                                                                          
>>>> Here check for "Found Proton" in the cmake output <<<<                                                                                       
$ make -j8                                                                                                                 
$ make install
```

Check that proton/engine.h is where you think it should be.  In your case, it looks like that would be /usr/local/include/proton/engine.h.

You can use the following command to see what your include search path is.

```
cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null
```